# i can't find any error

Tags: php, mysql

**can't reach header.php???**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {   $name = $_POST["firstname"];   $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];   $email = $_POST["email"];   $password = $_POST["password"];   $mobile = $_POST["mobile"];   $office_num = $_POST["office"];

  $sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert into `user_info`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `mobile`,`office_contact`) values('$name','$lastname','$email', '$password', '$mobile', $office_num)");

    if (mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        header("Location: header.php");
            } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbcon);  } ?>
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error: 1
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)**. Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: yes. i m storing password in plane text

Comment: @JohnConde I had to reopen the question John, they were calling `mysqli_query()` twice; that is why they're getting the `1` as the error ;-) edit: oh, and outputting before header.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `mysqli_query()` twice.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert into... $office_num)");
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ There

if (mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ and there
```

The conditional statement is calling it again. You need to remove the first query call, which explains the `1` coming back as the error.

Your code is also prone to an sql injection; use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You're also outputting before header with the following lines of code:

```
echo "New record created successfully"; // <<  Remove this line
        header("Location: header.php");
```

Remove the echo statement for it and add `exit;` after header to avoid further execution.

**Note:** Make sure that the value for `$office_num` is indeed an integer such as 5551234 and not 555-1234. If it is the latter, you will need to wrap that variable with quotes as you did for the other string values.

Don't store plain text passwords, especially if you're going live with this.

Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` and **please read over those manuals attentively:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php